# Unable to create Xpath equivalent to partial match of a CSS being `a[href*="https://stackexchange.com/"]`

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get:  the Hot Network Questions Href from https://stackoverflow.com/

Is there an Xpath equivalent to `a[href*="https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot"]`

```
//a[Href*"https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot"]
```

The below above works however...

```
//a[@href='https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot']
```

I want to be more specific and create a partial match...

So something like:

```
//acontains[@href='https://stacke']
```

or

```
//a[starts-with@href='https://stacke']
```

Is this possible with xpath?

Comment: Is there an XPath equivalent to XXX, where XXX is an expression written in some language that you haven't identified and whose semantics are likely to be unknown to most readers? Please explain what you want in English, not in some unknown language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//a[starts-with(@href='https://stacke') or contains(@href, 'https://stacke')]
```

Try this selector:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, ('https://stackexchange.com/questions'))]
```

Comment: Well I don't think its possible then